# Obtaining a single color name from a HEX input in R

Tags: r, colors

When using color.id from the plotrix package, is it possible to get ONLY a single colour returned not a vector of colours?
see this example:

```
color.id("#A1A295")
```

this returns:
"gray62" "grey62"

Is there a way (or another package) that simply returns a single colour name?

Thanks.

Comment: Save the value returned by `color.id`.  If its length is greater than one, take only the first element.  (Or any other, as you see fit.)  Wrap this in a function if you're going to be doing this more than a couple of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is vectorized function based on what Limey said.

```
get_color_name <- function(color_hex) {
  out = vector(length = length(color_hex))
  
  for(i in seq_along(color_hex)) {
    out[i] <- color.id(color_hex[i])[1]
  }
  out
  
}
get_color_name(rainbow(5))
>[1] "red"          "yellow2"      "springgreen2" "dodgerblue2"  "magenta2"   
get_color_name("#A1A295")
>[1] "gray62"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the function:

```
color.id2 <- function(col, distinct = FALSE) {
  #modified version of the color.id function in the plotrix package, author: Ben Bolker
  c2 <- col2rgb(col)
  coltab <- col2rgb(colors(distinct = distinct))
  cdist <- apply(coltab, 2, function(z) sum((z - c2)^2))
  colors(distinct = distinct)[which(cdist == min(cdist))]
}

color.id2("#A1A295", distinct = TRUE)
#[1] "gray62"
```

You could send the maintainer of the plotrix package a message and suggest replacing the function with this version.